# Can the out-signal from MAX4173 be slowed down?

Tags: voltage, current-measurement, comparator

I have designed a small voltage / current monitor that works perfect in a lab-setup. However, when I yesterday tried it in the real application, it latches immediately. The only reason I can think of as to now (I am going to confirm the error source in a minute) is that the in-rush current causes the current sensor to trip.

It makes sense, and the bad thing here is that I completely omitted that fact when I designed the circuit and fabricated the boards. I therefore will have to bite the bullet and patch all the boards.

See the image. That's the current sensor in a nut-shell: Rs = 10mohm shunt resistor. MAX4173 does its high side-magic using that resistor, and outputs the current as a linear voltage. This voltage is sent to a comparator with a fixed reference of 1.25V (equals 2.5A current in my setup). As soon as the comparator is tripped, a PNP pulls down and makes another part of the circuit latch, effectively stopping the power source.

Now; given the sad scenario where the boards are already done, is there a way to slow down the out-signal from MAX4173 a bit, without compromising the main feature (measuring current during normal operation) too much?

[image]

Comment: An RC low pass filter between the MAX4173 and comparitor would slow it down. Is that what you want though, as the comparitor would still slew very quickly once 1.25v was reached.

Comment: A capacitor to ground before the comparator input or a complete RC lowpass there would be a typical thing. What is the permissible delay for the latching? You could also add a capacitor in parallel with the shunt. Or maybe a slower comparator (may also be pin-compatible and even cheaper)?

Comment: Not much of a circuit.